# Retrieve data from every child with a where Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am structuring firebase to an coupon code system. What i am trying to achieve is, user cant use a coupon more than a specified limit. I have kept an couponUsage, by which each every coupon would have a per usage limit.

My Tree Structure:

[image]

In this, "2019","fortune", "happy" these are the coupon code names, and "9999999999" is the user mobile number (user UID). And the value is the number of the time the code is been used by the user for that particular coupon code.

So, what i did is, when ever a user uses a code then it will become a new entry under that code. And when user reuses the code, the value will be changing from 1 to 2 and beyond until the limit specified in another tree.

Here is my code:

```
export const fetchCouponCode = () => {
return (dispatch) => {
    firebase.database().ref('couponCodes').once('value', function(couponSnap){
        firebase.database().ref('couponUsages').once('value', function(usageSnap){
            console.log( extend({}, couponSnap.val(), usageSnap.val()));
        })
    })
  };
};
```

I am using redux, so this is my action file. In this i am able to fetch the whole node couponUsages. But what i need is to fetch only the mobile numbers on each child, for example there is three coupon code in this, and each has a user called 9999999999. So i need to fetch only this user from all the three coupons.

How to achieve this ? Because when user base starts to raise up, it wont be good to have whole data and filter particular data etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add more field to firebase like:

```
coupon
  fortune
     userid: 999999999
     quantity: 2
```

Then you can use

```
firebase.database().ref('couponCodes').child('fortune')
                   .orderByChild('userid')
                   .equalTo(999999999);
```

Remember to set `.indexOn` on rules

Or

You can have a coupon list just to store coupon keys, like this:

```
coupons
  userid
    fortune
    happy
```

You can retrieve keys fortune, happy, ... from here.

Or you change your coupons structure

```
coupons
  userid-9999999999
    fortune: 123
    happy: 434
```

Then retrieve `firebase.database().ref('coupons').child('userid-9999999999')`

Comment: Understood, but i dont wanna limit child('fortune') as, there can be dozens of coupon code. What i am expecting is to search specific user on each coupon codes.

Comment: so first you can create 1 field for couponList of user. You can get the list coupons from that. Then `once` from the list

Comment: Couldn't understand , couponList filed ? Can you explain briefly ?

Comment: Actually , I thought of this @tuledev.  But there is an another parent condition in which there is an over all usage of coupon , for example fortune can be used max of 500 times ! That's the reason I used coupon name instead of using userId ! As because of using coupon name I can count total uses under that by counting number of userId under each coupon code ! Any workaround for this ?

Comment: I don't think count child of a coupon is a good practice in firebase database at this time. What if you have 1mil children?. I usually use another field for counting. After you add a fortune coupon for a user, increase fortune_count 1.